# how could I implement such effect of progress bar in iOS

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I have customized track image and progress image, the point is I don't want them to be with the same width. But it seems like when I use setTrackImage and setProgressImage, they always keep the same wide. Now my implementation turns out as the first image, but I want the effect just like the second image.
[image: current effect]

[image: expected effect]

Comment: use a UISlider and disable user interaction. That way you have a knob that you can modify at will with any image, no matter how big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use UISlider and then remove the thumb image by simply adding an empty image.